# Convert TIF to JPG without increasing Bit Depth

Tags: java, image, image-processing, type-conversion

I am trying to convert TIF image to JPG image. For that I am using the following code :

```
    SeekableStream s = new FileSeekableStream(tiffUrl);
    TIFFDecodeParam param = null;
    ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(EXT_TIFFX, s, param);
    RenderedImage op = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(0);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(jpgUrl);
    JPEGEncodeParam jpgparam = new JPEGEncodeParam();
    jpgparam.setQuality(quality);               
    ImageEncoder en = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder(EXT_JEPGX, fos, jpgparam);
    en.encode(op);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    s.close();
```

Before conversion my image size was approx 92KB and Bit Depth = 1
After conversion my new jpg image size is approx 1573KB and Bit Depth = 24

I need to manage my new image under 100KB. And I suppose this can be done if I control the Bit Depth to 1 itself.

Is there any solution helpful to perform this ?

Comment: See libnetpbm, there is also some command line tools (netpbm). I assume that they can do it (if jfif (.jpeg) supports 1 bit pixles)

Comment: A simple way of keeping your image size under 100 KB would be to leave it alone. JPEG compression does not support a 1-bit pixel depth, and is useless for this sort of image.

Comment: What @squeamishossifrage says. :-) TIFF has several optimized, lossless compression algorithms for 1 bit/pixel data. For JPEG, you could use grayscale, but it would result in 8 bits/pixel (and be lossy). [JBIG](http://www.jpeg.org/jbig/) would be a better fit.

Comment: If your pixels are 1-bit deep, then why do you try JPEG compression? This compression is based on smoothing small color variations. Here you have only 2 colors, there is no such thing as small color variation.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should use Apache Commons Imaging as it is a advanced and complete imaging solution. I use this to write `Tiff` images to PDF. There are plenty of [examples](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/sampleusage.html). Hope this will helps !!